# how to concatenate more request in facebook's graph api?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

how to concatenate more request in  facebook's graph api?
I mean.. I have 2 complex request working on Graph api explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

my requests are:

myFaceboookID/videos/uploaded?fields=likes.limit(1000).fields(id),comments.limit(1000).fields(likes.fields(id),from)&until=10 minutes ago&since=12 months ago&limit=1000

and

myFaceboookID/posts?fields=likes.limit(1000).fields(id),comments.limit(1000).fields(likes.fields(id),from)&limit=1000&since=1 months ago&until=10 minutes ago

how can I make a single request to receive both responses together ?
I need to optimize my android application....

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/

Comment: You should use the Facebook SDK for Android, in it is a Request class, and you can create multiple Requests, and add them to a RequestBatch.

Comment: i am using Facebook sdk and  Request class for single request. i will check on Monday for multiple request and i will let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thansk a lot, 
for android the correct URL is : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/batch-requests/

The key is always "the batch request".

Comment: why putting dead links, please add your answer here